Bessel-like integral, with exponential and trigonometric functions involved
Does anyone know if the following integral can be written in a closed form expression and how? Thank you all;
$$I = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \sin\phi e^{\alpha\cos\phi+\beta\sin\phi} d\phi, \alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}^{+}$$
I am suspecting that the Modified Bessel function is involved, but I got stuck.
My attempt:
$$ I  =\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d}{d\beta} e^{\alpha\cos\phi+\beta\sin\phi} d\phi $$
$$ = \frac{d}{d\beta} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\alpha\cos\phi+\beta\sin\phi} d\phi$$
$$= \frac{d}{d\beta} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\cos(\phi-\phi_{0})} d\phi$$
$$ = \frac{d}{d\beta} \int_{t=0}^{2\pi} e^{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\cos(t)} dt $$
$$= \frac{d}{d\beta} I_{0}\left(\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)$$
$$ =2\pi\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}}  I_{1}\left(\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right), $$
Where $ \phi_{0}= \arccos \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}} \right)$  and in the last step I used the correspondent property for the derivative of the Modified Bessel function.
I am not sure if my attempt is correct, and if I have to explain something for the exchange of the derivative with the integral.

I wouldn't have thought to use the Feynman trick in that situation but it clears things up very nicely! The exchange of the derivative and integral is justified as your integral meets the requirements of the Leibniz integral rule (namely, the limits of integration are finite and the integrand and its derivative $d\beta$ are both continuous functions).

Thank you again! The Leibniz rule for integration is certainly what I needed.

I believe that, seeing as the exponential can be expanded in a series of powers of $\cos(\phi)$ and $\sin(\phi)$, the following residue method may be applied.

We set $z = e^{i\phi}$ such that as $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$, $z$ traces out the unit circle counterclockwise. Since $\frac{dz}{d\phi} = ie^{i\phi}$, $d\phi = \frac{dz}{iz}$ and we may write
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\phi)e^{\alpha\cos(\phi)+\beta\sin(\phi)}d\phi = \oint_C\frac{1}{2i}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\left[z+\frac{1}{z}\right] + \frac{\beta}{2i}\left[z-\frac{1}{z}\right]\right)\frac{dz}{iz}
$$
where $C$ is the unit circle counterclockwise and we have used the exponential formulae for $\cos(\phi)$ and $\sin(\phi)$. If we collect terms in this integral we may write it as
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\oint_C\left(1-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\exp\left(\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}-i\frac{\beta}{2}\right]z+\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}+i\frac{\beta}{2}\right]\frac{1}{z}\right)dz = -\frac{1}{2}\oint_C\left(1-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\exp\left(Az+\frac{B}{z}\right)dz
$$
where we have replaced the expressions in square brackets with $A$ and $B$.

We now consider the singular points of the integrand. The function being integrated has only one singularity: an essential singularity at $z=0$. Due to the singularity not being a pole, we must find the residue here by manually expanding the function as below (letting $f(z)$ be the integrand function).
$$
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \left(1-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)e^{Az}e^{B/z} \\
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nz^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{B^m}{m!z^m}\right) - \frac{1}{z^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nz^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{B^m}{m!z^m}\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nB^{n+1}}{n!(n+1)!} + \cdots\right) - \frac{1}{z^2}\left(z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^{n+1}B^n}{(n+1)!n!} + \cdots\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nB^{n+1} - A^{n+1}B^n}{(n+1)(n!)^2} + \cdots \\
&= \frac{B - A}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nB^n}{(n+1)(n!)^2} + \cdots \\
\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0}f(z) &= (B-A)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nB^n}{(n+1)(n!)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Now, if we consider $A$ and $B$, we find
$$
\begin{align*}
B-A &= \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+i\frac{\beta}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}-i\frac{\beta}{2}\right) = i\beta\\
AB &= \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+i\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}-i\frac{\beta}{2}\right) = \frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{4}
\end{align*}
$$
such that the residue becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0}f(z) &= i\beta\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)^n}{4^n(n+1)(n!)^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, we may use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral's value from this, yielding
$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2}\oint_C\left(1-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\exp\left(Az+\frac{B}{z}\right)dz &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(2\pi i\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0}f(z)\right) \\
&= \pi\beta\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)^n}{4^n(n+1)(n!)^2}
\end{align*}
$$
where WolframAlpha tells me that this infinite sum converges to an expression involving the "modified Bessel function of the first kind" for a final result of
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\phi)e^{\alpha\cos(\phi)+\beta\sin(\phi)}d\phi = 2\pi\beta\frac{I_1(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2})}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}.
$$

Thank you a lot for your answer! It makes perfect sense. Also, I like it way more than my approach, cause I think it's very natural intuitively, when there is an integral in terms of a variable (which is also the argument of trigonometric function) who runs from 0 to 2π, to consider the contour integral over the unit circle.

Given $\alpha,\beta$ let $\rho=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ and choose $\theta$ such that $\alpha = \rho \cos\theta,\beta = \rho \sin\theta$. Then the exponent becomes $$\rho \cos\theta \cos \phi +\rho \sin\theta \sin \phi=\rho\cos(\phi-\theta)$$
and thus the integral becomes $$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin\phi~  e^{\rho \cos(\phi-\theta)}d\phi$$
Shifting $\phi\to \phi+\theta$ and using periodicity, we obtain
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\phi+\theta)e^{\rho \cos \phi}\,d\phi\\
&=\cos\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\sin \phi~ e^{\rho \cos \phi}\,d\phi+\sin\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\cos \phi~ e^{\rho \cos \phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}
The first integral has an explicit antiderivative and vanishes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin \phi~e^{\rho \cos\phi}~d\phi=\left[-\frac{1}{\rho}e^{\rho \cos\phi}\right]_{0}^{2\pi}=0$$
That leaves the second integral, which corresponds to a standard integral representation of the modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_1(\rho)$. Hence $$I=\sin \theta \cdot 2\pi I_1(\rho)=\frac{2\pi \beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}I_1\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\right)$$
